# Inequalities and limits?

Tags: limits, inequality, functional-inequalities

Given a function $f$ such that $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} f(x) =0$, and want to see if $f(x) >0 $ or $f(x)<0$, but its so hard to tell(its very complicated function).

My approach to solve this problem is : find another function $g$ such that $g(x)$ is very big function and positive and multiply it with $f(x)$ and if the $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} f(x)g(x) = \infty$ then $f(x)>0$ for all sufficiently large number  and if  the $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} f(x)g(x) = -\infty$ then $f(x)<0$ for all sufficiently large number.

Is this approach valid ?! which means it does tell you if $f(x)>0$ or $f(x)<0$ for all sufficiently large numbers ?

Comment: Check the function $f(x) = \dfrac{\sin x} {x} $. The limit of $f$ is $0$ yet $f$ does not maintain a constant sign as $x\to\infty$. Further you can relax your conditions to $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) g(x) >0$ (or $<0$) instead of $\infty$ (or $-\infty$).

Comment: @ParamanandSingh i am sure that $f(x)g(x)$ will go to $\pm \infty$ but will not alternate, you can assume that it will be bigger than $0$ or less than $0$ but it will not alternate starting from $x_0$.

Comment: Perhaps you misinterpreted my comments. All I wanted to say was that if we chose $g$ such that it is positive as $x \to \infty$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)g(x) > 0$ then $f$ is positive as $x \to \infty$ and if $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)g(x) < 0$ then $f$ is negative as $x \to \infty$. We really don't need to have these limits of $f(x)g(x)$ as specifically $\pm\infty$.

Comment: Moreover like my first comment shows, if $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x) = 0$ then it is not necessary that $f$ maintains a constant sign as $x \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We assert validity with proofs.

Notice

By definition of limits, we have that
$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f(x) g(x) = \infty $ is equivalent to saying:

$\forall M >0 \exists X$ such that $x \ge X \implies f(x)g(x) > M \iff f(x) > \frac{M}{g(x)}$

thus for $f(x) >0$ it's sufficient to have $g(x) > 0$. If your choice of $g(x) >0$ then your derivation is valid.

Notice $f(x) > \frac{M}{g(x)}$ means that $f(x)$ can approach 0, for $g(x) \to \infty$, but will do it from the positive side.

Now the negative case.

By definition of limits, we have that
$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f(x) g(x) = -\infty $ is equivalent to saying:

$\forall M >0 \exists X$ such that $x \ge X \implies f(x)g(x) < -M \iff f(x) < -\frac{M}{g(x)}$

thus for $f(x) < 0$ it's sufficient to have $g(x) > 0$ just like in the positive case.

Notice $f(x) < -\frac{M}{g(x)}$ means that $f(x)$ can approach 0, for $g(x) \to \infty$, but will do it from the negative side.